# Python alphanumeric sorting for list of lists

Tags: python, sorting, alphanumeric

I'm currently trying to sort a list of the form:

```
[["Chr1", "949699", "949700"],["Chr11", "3219", "444949"],
["Chr10", "699", "800"],["Chr2", "232342", "235345234"],
["ChrX", "4567", "45634"],["Chr1", "950000", "960000"]]
```

Using the built-in `sorted()`, I get:

[['Chr1', '949699', '949700'], ['Chr1', '950000', '960000'], ['Chr10', '699', '800'], ['Chr11', '3219', '444949'], ['Chr2', '232342', '235345234'], ['ChrX', '4567', '45634']]

but I want "Chr2" to come before "Chr10". My current solution involves some code adapted from the page: [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

My current solution looks like this:

```
import re

def naturalSort(l): 
    convert= lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower() 
    alphanum_key= lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)] 
    if isinstance(l[0], list):
        return sorted(l, key= lambda k: [alphanum_key(x) for x in k])
    else:
        return sorted(l, key= alphanum_key)
```

Yielding the correct order:

```
[['Chr1', '949699', '949700'], ['Chr1', '950000', '960000'], ['Chr2', '232342', '235345234'], ['Chr10', '699', '800'], ['Chr11', '3219', '444949'], ['ChrX', '4567', '45634']]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is called 'natural sorting'.

Comment: Ah.. but i think this might not be a dupe, since he is trying to create it himself. But this question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I cited the natural sort page. I am specifically asking about sorting a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Did it like:

```
In [1]: l = [["Chr1", "949699", "949700"],["Chr11", "3219", "444949"],["Chr10", "699", "800"],["Chr2", "232342", "235345234"],["ChrX", "4567", "45634"],["Chr1", "950000", "960000"]]

In [2]: sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x[0].replace('Chr', '')) if x[0].replace('Chr', '').isdigit() else x[0])
Out[2]: 
[['Chr1', '949699', '949700'],
 ['Chr1', '950000', '960000'],
 ['Chr2', '232342', '235345234'],
 ['Chr10', '699', '800'],
 ['Chr11', '3219', '444949'],
 ['ChrX', '4567', '45634']]
```

Or more elegant variant:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(''.join([i for i in x[0] if i.isdigit()])) if re.findall(r'\d+$', x[0]) else x[0])
```

Comment: The input is not always of this form. Sometimes it can also be just "1", "2", "11", "X" without the "Chr" prefix.

Comment: Changed the sortering like `sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(''.join([i for i in x[0] if i.isdigit()])) if [i for i in x[0] if i.isdigit()] else x[0])`

Comment: More interesting variant: `import re; sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(''.join([i for i in x[0] if i.isdigit()])) if re.findall(r'\d+$', x[0]) else x[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more compact solution:

```
natkey = lambda e: [x or int(y) for x, y in re.findall(r'(\D+)|(\d+)', e)]
print sorted(data, key=lambda item: map(natkey, item))
```